# Solving the system of nonlinear PDE

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method

I have never used Mathematica before.
I am trying to solve the system of PDE

\begin{array}{l}     \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = D_u \nabla^2 u - \beta \chi_u \nabla ( u \nabla \pi_u) + u (\pi_u - \kappa (u+v)) \\ \frac{\partial v}{\partial t} = D_v \nabla^2 v - \beta \chi_v \nabla ( v \nabla \pi_v) + v (\pi_v - \kappa (u+v))  \end{array}

where

\begin{array}{l}         \pi_u = a \frac{u}{u + v} + b \frac{v}{u + v} \\
    \pi_v  = c \frac{u}{u + v} + d \frac{v}{u + v}  \end{array}

are the function with respect to $u$ and $v$.

And I am giving the initial values : $u$~Normal(44.444, 0.0001) and $v$~Normal(22.222, 0.0001)

And this is the Mathamatica Code I tried

```
{beta, chiu, chiv, kappa, Du, Dv} = {10, 0.3, 2.4, 0.001, 0.733, 0.733}
{a, b, c, d} = {-0.1, 0.4, 0, 0.2}
piu[u_, v_] := {a*(u/(u + v)) + b*(v/(u + v))}
piv[u_, v_] := {c*(u/(u + v)) + d*(v/(u + v))}
ph = NDSolveValue[{\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(u[t, x, y]\)\) == 
    Du*Inactive[Laplacian][u[t, x, y], {x, y}] - 
     beta*chiu*
      Inactivate[Grad][
       u[t, x, y]*(Inactivate[Grad][
          piu[u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + 
     u[t, x, y]*(piu[u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]] - 
        kappa*(u[t, x, y] + v[t, x, y])), \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(t\)]\(v[t, x, y]\)\) == 
    Dv*Inactive[Laplacian][v[t, x, y], {x, y}] - 
     beta*chiv*
      Inactivate[Grad][
       v[t, x, y]*(Inactivate[Grad][
          piv[u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]], {x, y}]), {x, y}] + 
     v[t, x, y]*(piv[u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]] - 
        kappa*(u[t, x, y] + v[t, x, y])), 
   u[t, x, -1] == u[t, x, 1] == u[t, -1, y] == u[t, 1, y] == 
    v[t, x, -1] == v[t, x, 1] == v[t, -1, y] == v[t, 1, y] == 0, 
   u[0, x, y] == RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[22.222, 0.0001]], 
   v[0, x, y] == 
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[44.444, 0.0001]]}, {u, v}, {t, 0,
    10}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

But the error message says that : Objects of unequal length in ...

Can anyone help me? Any advice or comments are welcome.

Comment: Expression `\[Del]\[Del]u[...]` gives vectorgradient. Perhaps your pde needs `\[Del]\[CenterDot]\[Del]u `

Comment: Grad[a Grad[b]] is undefined, probably by $\nabla(a \nabla(b))$ =   Div[a Grad[b,{x,y}],{x,y}] is physically and algebraically correct.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Can we solve this problem using `NDSolve` or not?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Ride hand side of the pde's is only scalar if we have the form `Grad[...]\[CenterDot] (...Grad[])`   ( dot product ) . For this case `NDSolve` should be able to solve. Still waiting for a reply to my first comment from OP

Comment: @random487510 Did you check the correct form of your pde's? By the way the  Initial conditions (`!=0`) and the boundary conditions (`==0`)  are inconsistent!

Comment: Could you say what equation model and give a reference?

Answer (score 4):

To long for a comment, as a reply to @AlexTrounev.

First change the definitions (no curly brakets!)

```
piu[u_, v_] := a*(u/(u + v)) + b*(v/(u + v))
piv[u_, v_] := c*(u/(u + v)) + d*(v/(u + v))
```

If we change the pde to `Grad[...Grad[]]` to `Div[...Grad[...]]` , which should be confirmed by the OP(!), we get system equations

```
eqns = {Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y] == 
       Du* Laplacian [u[t, x, y], {x, y}] - 
         beta*chiu*
           Inactive[Div] [
             u[t, x, y]* Inactive[Grad] [
                  piu[u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]], {x, y}] , {x, y}] + 
         u[t, x, y]*(piu[u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]] - 
               kappa*(u[t, x, y] + v[t, x, y])),
  Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][t, x, y] == 
       Dv* Laplacian [v[t, x, y], {x, y}] - 
         beta*chiv*
           Inactive[Div][
             v[t, x, y]* Inactive[ Grad] [
                  piv[u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]], {x, y}] , {x, y}] + 
         v[t, x, y]*(piv[u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]] - 
               kappa*(u[t, x, y] + v[t, x, y])) , 
     u[t, x, -1] == u[t, x, 1] == u[t, -1, y] == u[t, 1, y] == 
       v[t, x, -1] == v[t, x, 1] == v[t, -1, y] == v[t, 1, y] == 0, 
     u[0, x, y] == RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[22.222, 0.0001]], 
     v[0, x, y] == 
       RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[44.444, 0.0001]]}
```

Still there are nonlinearities on the right handside, which have to be linearized to make NDSolve FEM solver work.

I tried examplary  `Inactive[ Grad  [piv[u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]], {x, y}] ]` but did not succeed...

If I apply this last modification `NDSolve` gives following messages

"Grad::argtu: Grad called with 1 argument; 2 or 3 arguments are expected."

and

"NDSolve::femper: PDE parsing error of Grad[ -((0.1 u)/(u+v))+(0.4 v)/(u+v) ]. Inconsistent equation dimensions."

Any ideas?

**addendum**

Hoping my transformation are correct I actually get these pdes:

```
eqns = {Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y] == 
       Du* Laplacian [u[t, x, y], {x, y}] - 
         beta*chiu*
             
     Div [   ( 
       Inactivate[((a - b) v[t, x, y] u[t, x, 
            y])/(u[t, x, y] + v[t, x, y])^2] Grad   [
          u[t, x, y], {x, y}] - 
        Inactivate[((a - b) u[t, x, y] u[t, x, 
            y])/(u[t, x, y] + v[t, x, y])^2] Grad   [
          v[t, x, y], {x, y}]  ) , {x, y}] + 
         u[t, x, y]*
     Inactivate[(a*u[t, x, y]/(u[t, x, y] + v[t, x, y]) + 
        b*v[t, x, y]/(u[t, x, y] + v[t, x, y]) - 
                kappa*(u[t, x, y] + v[t, x, y]))],
  Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][t, x, y] == 
       Dv* Laplacian [v[t, x, y], {x, y}] - 
         beta*chiv*
             
     Div  [(Inactivate[((c - d) v[t, x, y] v[t, x, 
            y])/(u[t, x, y] + v[t, x, y])^2] Grad   [
          u[t, x, y], {x, y}] - 
        Inactivate[((c - d) u[t, x, y] v[t, x, 
            y])/(u[t, x, y] + v[t, x, y])^2] Grad   [
          v[t, x, y], {x, y}]  ), {x, y}] + 
         v[t, x, y]*
     Inactivate[(c*u[t, x, y]/(u[t, x, y] + v[t, x, y]) + 
        d*v[t, x, y]/(u[t, x, y] + v[t, x, y]) - 
                kappa*(u[t, x, y] + v[t, x, y])) ], 
     DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == 0, True], 
  DirichletCondition[v[t, x, y] == 0, True] , 
     u[0, x, y] == RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[22.222, 0.0001]], 
     v[0, x, y] == 
       RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[44.444, 0.0001]]}
```

But solution fails

```
NDSolve[eqns, {u, v}, {t, 0, 10}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t,"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}]
```

error message is unclear to me "NDSolve::underdet: There are more dependent variables, {u[t,x,y],v[t,x,y],u[t,x,y],v[t,x,y]}, than equations, so the system is underdetermined."

**final(?) addendum**

[image]

My handmade transformation give this form of the two pde's.
Actually I don't know how to inactivate parts of these equations to get standard form accepted by the FEM solver...

Comment: So, FEM failed. Maybe we can use  "MethodOfLines"?

Comment: @AlexTrounev Yess, MethodOfLines and FiniteElement. But pde has to be prepared to avoid parsing error

Comment: Try `Activate[eqns]`, then you will see real problem of FEM .

Comment: @AlexTrounev What exactly do you mean? Mathematica v12.2 shows two nonlinear pde's without error message

Comment: Use activation in `NDSolve` :)

Comment: @AlexTrounev Please have a look on **addendum** in my answer.

Comment: Let try `"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid",...`

Comment: @AlexTrounev "TensorPtoductGrid" gives the same message!

Comment: This equation system drives Mathematica crazy.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that we can't solve this system of PDEs using `NDSolve`. Nevertheless we can solve it as system of ODEs using hand made method of lines code as follows

```
noise = 0.01; conu0 = 22.222; conv0 = 44.444;


{beta, chiu, chiv, kappa, du, dv} = {9.8, 0.3, 2.4, 0.001, 0.733, 
   0.733};
{a, b, c, d} = {-0.1, 0.4, 0, 0.2};
piu[u_, v_] := a*(u/(u + v)) + b*(v/(u + v));
piv[u_, v_] := c*(u/(u + v)) + d*(v/(u + v));

XYgrid[dom_List, pts_List] := 
  MapThread[
   N@Range[Sequence @@ #1, Abs[Subtract @@ #1]/#2] &, {dom, 
    pts - 1}];
BoundaryIndex[xgridlen_, ygridlen_] := 
  Module[{tmp, left, right, bot, top}, 
   tmp = Table[(n - 1) ygridlen + Range[1, ygridlen], {n, 1, 
      xgridlen}]; {left, right} = tmp[[{1, -1}]]; {bot, top} = 
    Transpose[{First[#], Last[#]} & /@ tmp]; {top, right[[2 ;; -2]], 
    bot, left[[2 ;; -2]]}];
FDMat[deriv_, xygrid_, difforder_] := 
 Map[NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[#, xygrid, 
     "DifferenceOrder" -> difforder]["DifferentiationMatrix"] &, deriv]
{tmax, domain, pts, difforder} = {10, {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, {21, 21}, 4};
xygrid = XYgrid[domain, pts]; {nx, ny} = 
 Map[Length, xygrid]; {top, right, bot, left} = 
 BoundaryIndex[nx, ny]; {dx, dy, dx2, dy2} = 
 FDMat[{{1, 0}, {0, 1}, {2, 0}, {0, 2}}, xygrid, difforder]; {uvar0, 
  vvar0} = Table[ConstantArray[0, {nx ny, tmax}], {2}]; boundaries = 
 Join[top, right, bot, left]; sgrid = 
 Flatten[Outer[List, Sequence @@ xygrid], 1];
uvar = Table[uu[i][t], {i, nx ny}]; vvar = Table[vv[i][t], {i, nx ny}];

eqnu = du (dx2 + dy2) . uvar + 
  uvar (piu[uvar, vvar] - kappa (uvar + vvar)) - 
  beta chiu (dx . (uvar dx . piu[uvar, vvar]) + 
     dy . (uvar dy . piu[uvar, vvar])); eqnv = 
 dv (dx2 + dy2) . vvar + 
  vvar (piv[uvar, vvar] - kappa (uvar + vvar)) - 
  beta chiv (dx . (vvar dx . piv[uvar, vvar]) + 
     dy . (vvar dy . piv[uvar, vvar]));

nxy = Complement[Range[1, nx ny], boundaries]; iniu = 
 Table[uu[i][0] == conu0 + noise*RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {i, 
   nx ny}]; iniv = 
 Table[vv[i][0] == conv0 + noise RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {i, nx ny}];
```

This system of ODEs we can solve with `NDSolve`. Before do this we should note that system is unstable at $\beta>9.75$, while author asked to solve it at $\beta =10$. As compromise we solve it at $\beta=9.8$, but solution lost stability at `t = 0.8939960639052812`

```
sol = NDSolveValue[
   Join[Table[uu[i]'[t] == eqnu[[i]], {i, nxy}], 
    Table[vv[i]'[t] == eqnv[[i]], {i, nxy}], 
    Table[uu[i]'[t] == 0, {i, boundaries}], 
    Table[vv[i]'[t] == 0, {i, boundaries}], iniu, iniv], 
   Join[uvar, vvar], {t, 0, 1}, Method -> "ImplicitRungeKutta", 
   AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 4, MaxSteps -> 10^6];
```

Note that we start from random initial conditions that look like

```
{u, v} = 
  Map[Interpolation@Join[sgrid, Transpose@List@#, 2] &, 
   Partition[sol /. t -> .0, Length[sgrid]]];

{ContourPlot[u[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Contours -> 20, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotLabel -> "u", 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 ContourPlot[v[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Contours -> 20, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> "v", PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Figure 1]

Final state looks quite coherent

```
{u, v} = 
  Map[Interpolation@Join[sgrid, Transpose@List@#, 2] &, 
   Partition[sol /. t -> .89, Length[sgrid]]];

{ContourPlot[u[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Contours -> 20, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotLabel -> "u", 
  PlotRange -> All], 
 ContourPlot[v[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Contours -> 20, 
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
  PlotLabel -> "v", PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image: Figure 2]

**Update 1.** We can compare solution computed with code above at `beta=2` to solution computed with code proposed by Ulrich Neumann. First note that in his code there is a typo in equation for `v`, and after clean up his code looks as follows (we generate `mesh` same as `sgrid` above)

```
SeedRandom[1234];
<< NDSolve`FEM`
t0 = 1;
reg = Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]; mesh = 
 ToElementMesh[reg, "MaxCellMeasure" -> 1/110, 
  "MeshElementType" -> QuadElement];
n = Length[
  mesh["Coordinates"]]; noise = 0.01; conu0 = 22.222; conv0 = 44.444;
u0 = ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, 
  conu0 + noise*(RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n])]; v0 = 
 ElementMeshInterpolation[{mesh}, 
  conv0 + noise*(RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n])];
{beta, chiu, chiv, kappa, Du, Dv} = {2, 0.3, 2.4, 0.001, 0.733, 0.733};
{a, b, c, d} = {-0.1, 0.4, 0, 0.2};
piu[u_, v_] := a*(u/(u + v)) + b*(v/(u + v));
piv[u_, v_] := c*(u/(u + v)) + d*(v/(u + v));


solI = NestList[
   NDSolveValue[{Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y] == 
       Inactive[
          Div][(Du - 
            beta chiu (a - 
               b) (#[[1]][t, x, y] #[[2]][t, x, 
                 y])/((#[[1]][t, x, y] + #[[2]][t, x, 
                   y])^2)) Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, 
          y}] + Inactive[
          Div][(beta chiu (a - 
              b) (#[[1]][t, x, y] #[[1]][t, x, 
                y])/((#[[1]][t, x, y] + #[[2]][t, x, y])^2)) Inactive[
            Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
        u[t, x, y]*(piu[#[[1]][t, x, y], #[[2]][t, x, y]] - 
           kappa*(#[[1]][t, x, y] + #[[2]][t, x, y])), 
      Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][t, x, y] == 
       Inactive[
          Div][(Dv + 
            beta chiv (c - 
               d) (#[[1]][t, x, y] #[[2]][t, x, 
                 y])/((#[[1]][t, x, y] + #[[2]][t, x, 
                   y])^2)) Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, 
          y}] - Inactive[
          Div][(beta chiv (c - 
              d) (#[[2]][t, x, y] #[[2]][t, x, 
                y])/((#[[1]][t, x, y] + #[[2]][t, x, y])^2)) Inactive[
            Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
        v[t, x, y]*(piv[#[[1]][t, x, y], #[[2]][t, x, y]] - 
           kappa*(#[[1]][t, x, y] + #[[2]][t, x, y])), 
      DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == u0[x, y], True], 
      DirichletCondition[v[t, x, y] == v0[x, y], True], 
      u[0, x, y] == u0[x, y], v[0, x, y] == v0[x, y]}, {u, v}, {t, 0, 
      1}, Element[{x, y}, mesh], 
     Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}] &, {u0[x, y] &, 
    v0[x, y] &}, 3];
```

Visualization

```
GraphicsRow[{ContourPlot[solI[[-1, 1]][1, x, y], 
   Element[{x, y}, region], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   Contours -> 20, PlotLegends -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic,
    PlotLabel -> "u", PlotRange -> All], 
  ContourPlot[solI[[-1, 2]][1, x, y], Element[{x, y}, region], 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Contours -> 20, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
   PlotLabel -> "v", PlotRange -> All]}]
```

[image: Figure 3]

In my code we put `beta=2` and use same pseudorandom generator state `SeedRandom[1234]`, as result we have
[image: Figure 4]

Note that pictures look very similar, but we also can compare  detailed pictures as

```
py = {Plot[solI[[-1, 1]][1, 0, y], {y, -1, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}], 
  Plot[solI[[-1, 2]][1, 0, y], {y, -1, 1}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}]};
py1={Plot[u[0, y], {y, -1, 1}], Plot[v[0, y], {y, -1, 1}]};
{Show[py1[[1]],py[[1]]],Show[py1[[1]],py[[1]]]}
```

[image: Figure 5]

Here solid lines computed with my code and dashed lines computed with Ulrich code. The agreement is fine. Therefore we pass test at `beta=2`.
Test for `beta=9` gives last stably solution computed with Ulrich code
[image: Figure 6]

Same solution computed with my code
[image: Figure 7]

Since solutions look like identical we can conclude that Ulrich code and my code passes test at `beta=9` as well. For `beta=9.8` Ulrich code runs forever without answer, while with my code we have picture shown above.

Comment: Nice solution (+1) Which pde's did you use? The "Div[Grad[...]]" form?

Comment: Yes, we convert "inactive" form in matrix form. Maybe it could be better to use an activated form.

Comment: Thanks. I am still trying 
to find a FEM solution, perhaps iterative , but couldn't find a correct maybe inactive form

Comment: Meanwhile I got a nonlinear FEM-solution(see my second answer)  , which unfortunately differs form your solution. Have to check the pde-system...

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Please, make initial condition same to my solution and fix boundary conditions  at initial condition (the author wanted homogeneous boundary conditions, but this is wrong). Note, that  initial condition you used are not random.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Please see Update 1 to my answer with test for my and yours code for `beta=2`.

Comment: My latest insight: If you remove `, Method -> "ImplicitRungeKutta", 
   AccuracyGoal -> 5, PrecisionGoal -> 4, MaxSteps -> 10^6` in `sol` you get complete stationary solution in the time range `0<t<10` !

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thank you very much for your help.  But this options we need for `beta >9.85`, not for `beta=9.8`.

Comment: But this option decreases the simulation time `<<tmax` and gives a nonstationaer solution I think

Answer (score 3):

**modified typo corrected, thanks @AlexTrounev**

With manual transformation using [image]

it's possible to find an iterative FEM solution:

```
region=Rectangle[{-1,-1},{1,1}]
{beta, chiu, chiv, kappa, Du, Dv} = {2, 0.3, 2.4, 0.001, 0.733,0.733}
{a, b, c, d} = {-0.1, 0.4, 0, 0.2}


u0 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[22.222, 0.0001]];
v0 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[44.444, 0.0001]];

solI = NestList[
   NDSolveValue[{Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, y] == 
       Inactive[
          Div][(Du - 
            beta chiu (a - b) (#[[1]][t, x, y] #[[2]][t, x, 
               y])/((#[[1]][t, x, y] +  #[[2]][t, x, 
                y])^2) ) Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] +
         Inactive[
          Div][( beta chiu (a - b) (#[[1]][t, x, y] #[[1]][t, x, 
              y])/((#[[1]][t, x, y] +  #[[2]][t, x, y])^2) ) Inactive[
            Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
        u[t, x, y]*(piu[#[[1]][t, x, y], #[[2]][t, x, y]] - 
           kappa*(#[[1]][t, x, y] + #[[2]][t, x, y])),
      Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][t, x, y] == 
       Inactive[
          Div][(Dv + 
            beta chiv (c - d) (#[[1]][t, x, y] #[[2]][t, x, 
               y])/((#[[1]][t, x, y] + #[[2]][t, x, y])^2) ) Inactive[
            Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] - 
        Inactive[
          Div][( beta chiv (c - d) (#[[2]][t, x, y] #[[2]][t, x, 
              y])/((#[[1]][t, x, y] +   #[[2]][t, x, 
               y])^2) ) Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
        v[t, x, 
          y]*(piv[#[[1]][t, x, y], #[[2]][t, x, y]] - 
           kappa*(#[[1]][t, x, y] + #[[2]][t, x, y])), 
      DirichletCondition[u[t, x, y] == u0, True], 
      DirichletCondition[v[t, x, y] == v0
       , True] , u[0, x, y] == u0, v[0, x, y] == v0
      }, {u, v}, {t, 0, 10}, Element[{x, y}, region], 
     Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}] &, {u0 &, v0 &},
    3];

GraphicsRow[{ContourPlot[solI[[-1, 1]][10, x, y], 
   Element[{x, y}, region], ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   Contours -> 20, PlotLegends -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic,
    MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotLabel -> "u", 
   PlotRange -> All] , 
  ContourPlot[solI[[-1, 2]][10, x, y], Element[{x, y}, region], 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", Contours -> 20, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
   MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 50, PlotLabel -> "v", 
   PlotRange -> All] }]
```

[image]

It would be very helpful to find the inactive form of the **nonlinear** equations,  because we could avoid the slow iterative solution!

Any ideas?

Comment: Your code is not complete. Du, Dv are not defined.

Comment: Sorry, I added the definitions!

Comment: Thank you (+1). It looks like your code working as an averaging procedure.  With my code we can generate same picture for `beta=2`.

Comment: Please check, maybe there is a typo in your code in equation for `v`.

Comment: @AlexTrounev Where exactly do you suspect the error?

Comment: @AlexTrounev  The equations in `u` and `v`  are similar, only the parts `u` ,`v` have to be interchanged to get the other equation. That's why the coefficients in the equations  `Du-beta chiu` and `Dv-beta chiv` seem to be coreect I think.

Comment: No, there is a typo with sign in equation for v since expression you show above is antisymmetric. See Update 1 to my answer with testing your code compare to my code.

Comment: @AlexTrounex Got it, thanks!

Comment: Thanks to you for this very good method to solve PDEs.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, first time for me to give three answers to one very interesting question

If we ara looking for a stationary solution of the two pde's we can give a fast nonlinear Finite Element solution as follows. Here a assume random start conditions `InitialSeeding` and fix the boundary accordingly.

mesh and interpolation for `InitialSeeding`:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
region = ToElementMesh[Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]];
pts = region["Coordinates"];
ui = Map[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[22.222, 0.01]] &, pts];
ipu = ElementMeshInterpolation[region, ui](* InitialSeeding u[x,y]*)
vi = Map[ RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[44.444, 0.01]] &, pts];
ipv = ElementMeshInterpolation[region, vi](* InitialSeeding v[x,y]*)
```

parameters:

```
{beta, chiu, chiv, kappa, Du, Dv} = {10  , 0.3, 2.4, 0.001, 0.733,0.733}
{a, b, c, d} = {-0.1, 0.4, 0, 0.2}
piu[u_, v_] := a*(u/(u + v)) + b*(v/(u + v))
piv[u_, v_] := c*(u/(u + v)) + d*(v/(u + v))

c11 = Du - beta chiu (a - b) (u[x, y] v[x, y])/(u[x, y] + v[x, y])^2;
c12 = beta chiu (a - b) (u[x, y] u[x, y])/(u[x, y] + v[x, y])^2;
c21 = -beta chiv (c - d) (v[x, y] v[x, y])/(u[x, y] + v[x, y])^2;
c22 = Dv + beta chiv (c - d) (u[x, y] v[x, y])/(u[x, y] + v[x, y])^2;
```

nonlinear FEM solver

```
solS = NDSolveValue[{0 == 
     Inactive[Div][(- {{c11, 0}, {0, c11}}) . 
        Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
      Inactive[Div][(- {{c12, 0}, {0, c12}}) . 
        Inactive[Grad][v[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
      u[x, y]*(piu[u[x, y], v[x, y]] - kappa*(u[x, y] + v [x, y])),
    0 == Inactive[Div][ (- {{c21, 0}, {0, c21}}) . 
        Inactive[Grad][v[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] - 
      Inactive[Div][(- {{c22, 0}, {0, c22}}) . 
        Inactive[Grad][u[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] + 
      v[x, y]*(piv[u[x, y], v[x, y]] - kappa*(u[x, y] + v[x, y])), 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == ipu[x, y], True], 
    DirichletCondition[v[x, y] == ipv[x, y]
     , True]  
    }, {u, v} , Element[{x, y}, region] , 
   "InitialSeeding" -> {u[x, y] == ipu[x, y], v[x, y] == ipv[x, y]} , 
   Method -> "PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}] ;
```

solution plot:

```
GraphicsRow[{ 
  Plot3D[solS[[ 1]][ x, y], Element[{x, y}, region], 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 50, 
   PlotLabel -> "u[x,y] (beta=" <> ToString[beta] <> ")", 
   PlotRange -> All] , 
  Plot3D[solS[[ 2]][ x, y], Element[{x, y}, region], 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
   AspectRatio -> Automatic, MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 50, 
   PlotLabel -> "v[x,y] (beta=" <> ToString[beta] <> ")", 
   PlotRange -> All] }]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for `NDSolve` solution (+1), but this is the  final stage only.  How to force `NDSolve` to solve this system on $0\le t \le 1$?

Comment: I tried the transient case too, but got error message "LinearSolve::exopt1: The option setting Method -> Multifrontal cannot be used with arbitrary-precision or exact arguments."